# Reflection-generated and generic types

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm having yet another nasty moment with `Reflection.Emit` and type management.

Say, I have a type named `MyType` which is defined in the dynamically generated assembly.
Calling `MyType.GetMethods()` results in a `NotSupportedException`, which has reduced me to writing my own set of wrappers and lookup tables. However, the same is happening when I'm calling `GetMethods()` or any other introspecting methods on standard generic types which use my own types as generic arguments:

- `Tuple<int, string>` => works fine
- `Tuple<int, MyType>` => exception

I can get the method list from the generic type definition:

`typeof(Tuple<int, MyType).GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetMethods()`

However, the methods have generic placeholders instead of actual values (like `T1`, `TResult` etc.) and I don't feel like writing yet another kludge that traces the generic arguments back to their original values.

A sample of code:

```
var asmName = new AssemblyName("Test");
var access = AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run;
var asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, access);
var module = asm.DefineDynamicModule("Test");

var aType = module.DefineType("A");
var tupleType = typeof(Tuple<,>);
var tuple = tupleType.MakeGenericType(new [] { typeof(int), aType });

tuple.GetProperty("Item1"); // <-- here's the error
```

So the questions are:

1. How do I detect if a type is safe to call `GetMethods()` and similar methods on?
2. How do I get the actual list of methods and their generic argument values, if the type is not safe?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Also, give more details about the `NotSupportedException` - is there nothing in the message?

Comment: @JonSkeet, the exception simply says "The method is not supported" or something like that. I'm running a Russian version of Windows, so I don't know the exact message, but it contains no additional information. The stacktrace only has my `GetMethods()` and `System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilderInstantiation.GetMethods(BindingFlags bindingAttr)` inside it.

Comment: If you need those `MethodInfo`s (etc.) because you are still busy *building* the type, you do in fact have to keep track of the original `MethodBuilder`s (etc.) for use in method invocations and other emitted calls.  If you need the `MethodInfo`s (etc.) after you've already called `CreateType`, then, as Eric answered, you can invoke those methods on the created type.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I'm busy building _another_ type. For example, I have types `A` and `B`. Type `B` has a method that uses `Tuple<int, A>` and needs to get `tuple.Item1` out of it. I detect the type of `tuple` variable and call `GetProperties()` on it. There are no `MethodBuilder`s to track since I have not defined this type, but merely instantiated it by applying generic arguments.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have added a small snippet of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got an answer in a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669387). The `TypeBuilder` class has a bunch of static overloads which do exactly the thing:

```
var genericTuple = typeof(Tuple<,>);
var myTuple = genericTuple.MakeGenericType(typeof(int), myType);
var ctor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(myTuple, genericTuple.GetConstructors().First());
```

Strangely, there's no overload of `GetProperty`. However, property getters and setters can still be resolved using `GetMethod`:

```
var genericGetter = typeof(Tuple<,>).GetProperty("Item1").GetMethod;
var actual = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(myTuple, genericGetter);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll refer you to the documentation:

[Defining a Type with Reflection Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kyyyeh2.aspx)

which says

> Although TypeBuilder is derived from Type, some of the abstract methods defined in the Type class are not fully implemented in TypeBuilder. These TypeBuilder methods throw the NotSupportedException. The desired functionality can be obtained by retrieving the created type using Type.GetType or Assembly.GetType and reflecting on the retrieved type.

So:

> How do I detect if a type is safe to call GetMethods() and similar methods on?

If the type object is a TypeBuilder, or if the type refers to any type that is a TypeBuilder, then it is not safe to do so.

> How do I get the actual list of methods and their generic argument values, if the type is not safe?

I'll refer you to the documentation again. Actually emit the type into an assembly and then get it out of the assembly.

Comment: Checking if a type is a `TypeBuilder` is easy, but how do I check if a type *refers* to a `TypeBuilder`?

Comment: @Impworks: Why do you need to check it? Just do all your type building, emit the assembly, and *then* start using the types. It's not really clear what your bigger aim is, but Eric's advice looks like the way forward to me.

Comment: As for the idea to emit the type into assembly, types may be cross-dependent. Like, `A` uses a `List<B>` and `B` uses a `List<A>`. I can't emit either type completely and finalize it with `CreateType`.

Comment: @Impworks: Why do you need to use `GetMethods()` while defining those types though? Define both of them, then emit the assembly, then do whatever you need with them. It sounds like there's a lot of context here that you haven't included in your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'm creating a compiler that has two phases: during the first I create a `TypeBuilder` for each type defined in the source, during the second I generate the code of the methods. Generating the code requires a lot of lookups for types that might be returned from other lookups.

Comment: @Impworks: Ah, now we come to it.  **Reflection.Emit is too weak to use to build a real compiler**. It's great for little toy compilation tasks like emitting dynamic call sites and expression trees in LINQ queries, but for the sorts of problems you'll face in a compiler you will quickly exceed its capabilities. Use CCI, not Reflection.Emit.